# Remove the typing functionality on my dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

```
<select class="" id="js-select2" multiple="multiple">
          <option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
        </select>

    $('#js-select2').select2({
      placeholder: "Select your option",
      allowClear: true
    });
```

I am using this to create a dropdown with my options, the options appear correctly however the select allows the user to type and searches. I want it to be a simple button with an arrow aligned to the right that on clicked displays all my options. How can i do this?

I've tried playing with the styling and using select2-dropdown however it doesn't seem to do anything. This seems like a simple fix but I am apparently having brain block

Comment: Read [documentation](https://select2.org/searching#limiting-display-of-the-search-box-to-large-result-sets). Set `minimumResultsForSearch = -1` to disable search feature

Comment: DIdn't work. I tried minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity as well and that also did not work

Comment: Than please provide minimal example of your code inside SO Snippet. Maybe you have some very old version of Selec2 library?

Comment: I cant really show much because of NDA. I think the issue stems from the fact that im using a multi select. https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4797 I see that its been brought up and there is a workaround but even the workaround doesn't work super well. I'm using php to populate the options and that works correctly so its just a matter of understanding this but if there isn't built in functionality then i dont know what to do

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by SO snippet, sorry to ask but just to be sure

Comment: When editing your question there is 7th icon (or Ctrl + M) to add executable code blocks in questions. Please use it to demonstrate not working behaviour.

Comment: I couldnt figure it out, kept giving me script errors when setting it up and i am on a major time constraint at work so i dont have time to figure that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For single select use `minimumResultsForSearch = -1`.

For multiple select set `disabled` on search field (as stated in [documentation](https://select2.org/searching#multi-select)):

> For multi-select boxes, there is no distinct search control. So, to disable search for multi-select boxes, you will need to set the disabled property to true whenever the dropdown is opened or closed

```js
$('#js-select2')
  .select2({
    placeholder: "Select your option",
    allowClear: true
  })
  .on('select2:opening select2:closing', function(event) {
    var $searchfield = $(this).parent().find('.select2-search__field');
    $searchfield.prop('disabled', true);
  });
```

```css
select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select id="js-select2" multiple="multiple">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This works but its buggy on my system. I will mark it as the answer but i think i will personally just give up on this because I've been slamming my head against it all day

Comment: @Danielelkhal Well, it's official documentation, so maybe they will fix it some day if you fill in support ticket for them. Also note that there are plenty of other libraries to use or even implement yourself. I used to be using Chosen, but it seems to be deprecated

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/select/

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:-

```
<script>
// In your Javascript (external .js resource or <script> tag)
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $select2 = $('.js-select2');

    $select2.select2({
        placeholder: "Select your option",
        allowClear: true,
    });

    // Add a class to the select2-container when opening
    var $searchField = $('.select2-search__field');
    
    $select2.on('select2:open', function (e) {
        $searchField.prop('readonly', true);
    });

    // Block the Backspace key in the search box
    $searchField.on('keydown', function (e) {
        if ($searchField.prop('readonly') && e.key === 'Backspace') {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false; // To prevent further processing of the event
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Please try this and update here.

Comment: This stops me from typing but it only works once, after the first click the dropdown freezes completely

Comment: Yes I checked. But if you try to click on left top corner of the select box then toggle should work properly. I am checking how we can fix this.

Comment: Hey @Danielelkhal, I have updated above code and it's working perfectly fine at my end. Please try this code. I think it will work for you.